# Changing MATLAB's startup folder in Linux

Tags: linux, matlab

I have followed the instructions [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_env/assign-userpath-as-the-startup-folder-on-unix-or-macintosh.html) with no sucess:

- I export the following variable in `.bashrc`:

  ```
  export MATLAB_USE_USERPATH=1
  ```

  I can verify the above loads correctly with `echo $MATLAB_USE_USERPATH` before I run MATLAB.
- I have also run the following lines from MATLAB:

  ```
  userpath('reset')
  userpath('clear')
  userpath('/path/to/my/startup')
  ```

But still MATLAB starts in my home directory, and not in `/path/to/my/startup`.

Is there anything else I need to do? Can I edit the `startup` folder manually in `matlab.prf`?

Thanks

Comment: It says `export MATLAB_USE_USERPATH=1`. Above you have `USER_USERPATH`.

Comment: Thanks @reve_etrange. I fixed that in the OP. I have it correct on my `.bashrc`

Comment: I assume you made sure `.bashrc` got sourced?  Have you tried exporting the variable directly in your shell and then starting MATLAB from that shell?  Does it start in your home or in your `Documents/MATLAB`?

Comment: @reve, yes. `.bashrc` is sourced and I have tried exporting the variable directly as well.

Comment: @reve, it starts on my home directory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know the regular way to do this, but the easy way is just settings the userpath to your directory of personal scripts.

In that folder, you put a script `startup.m` which contains:

```
cd /path/to/my/startup
```

It might not look pretty, but this allows you to change the directory depending on other factors. I have seen examples of people who get a prompt at startup that asks 'Which project are you working on?' and depending on their input some files are loaded, the direcotry is changed, etc. Personally, I load settings from different locations depending on what computer MATLAB is working on (home computer, personal computer at my university, computer rooms at university, ...)

**edit:** Perhaps just a small idea that might help you along with those variables: you can always try to edit the MATLAB start script for Linux (not `startup.m` but the bash script returned by `which matlab` in your shell).

Comment: I think is the right way to do it.  You put `startup.m` in your `Documents/MATLAB`.  Every time you start MATLAB, the `USERPATH` is added to the `MATLABPATH`, so you might eventually get bitten if the `USERPATH` is a working directory and not your scripts directory.

Comment: @reve_etrange: are you arguing that it is or is not the right way? The `user path`, as far as I know, is to be used to add personal functions, scripts, personal toolboxes, common data files, ... to your path; it is not supposed to be a real working directory so I guess that border case is extremely unlikely to occur.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say "*this* is the right way to do it."  I was trying to imply the same about the `USERPATH`, that's why the `cd` in a startup script is better than changing it.  I should have been more clear.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, there is a bug in the documentation, and the correct environment variable name is `MATLAB_USE_USERWORK` (i.e. `...WORK`, not `...PATH`). Make that change, and you should be all set!

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is as follows:
(assume your desired startup folder is : /home/matlab/myspace)

1- add this path to your paths using **userpath(/home/matlab/myspace)** and then **savepath**

2- create **startup.m** file with the following content

```
  cd /home/matlab/myspace
```

3- put **startup.m** file in /home/matlab/myspace

That is it, you should startup in your desired folder.

Answer (score 0):

There is a file called **matopts.sh** or **matopts.cmd** based on the operating system.

We have to change the value of a variable in the file so that when this file is called in the starting of matlab to set the environment it change the root folder to the value specified.

There are proper comments specified to help us customize the file.