# changing matlab startup current folder

Tags: matlab

I installed matlab R13a a while ago. When it starts up the current working directory is the bin folder. But I don't want it to be so. How can I change the current folder so that when I run matlab it starts initially in that folder?

Comment: If this is on Windows machine, it is enough to change startup folder of your MatLab shortcut.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create (or modify) a [startup script](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/startup.html) in your MATLAB root directory (or anywhere on your MATLAB search path) with the **exact** name of `startup.m`. All you write in this script will execute each time MATLAB is started. There you can change current folder using [`cd`](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cd.html):

```
cd('the_starting_root_you_prefer')
```

And save it. If you want to know your root directory, use [`matlabroot`](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlabroot.html).

Comment: Thank you it worked! But it takes a second or two to move to the folder I specified. Isn't there any faster trick?

Comment: Take a look at other suggested ways [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7826460/changing-matlabs-startup-folder-in-linux?rq=1). I just found it.

Comment: MATLAB executes `startup.m` once it is done initializing, which could indeed take a second or two, but you won't be able to execute any other code before initialization is done anyway, so this isn't really an issue of startup speed.

Answer (score 2):

You might consider [setting the startup directory to be the last directory from the previous MATLAB session](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/95875-is-it-possible-to-set-the-startup-directory-to-be-the-directory-i-was-in-when-i-ended-the-previous-s) by editing both [`startup.m`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/startup.html) and [`finish.m`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/finish.html). In `startup.m`, enter:

```
if (exist([matlabroot filesep 'last_dir.mat']) == 2)
    load ([matlabroot filesep 'last_dir'])
    cd(last_dir)
    clear last_dir
end
```

In `finish.m`, enter:

```
last_dir = pwd;
save([matlabroot filesep 'last_dir'], 'last_dir')
```

MATLAB will now start where you left it at the end of the last session. Note this won't work if MATLAB stopped unexpectedly (i.e., crashed).

Comment: nice! I didn't know about `finish.m`

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't work here. I did the same as you said but it never went to the last dir at all. With a startup script @Erfan suggested I was able to view a specified folder every time I launched matlab.